# Getting None Type and Invalid Literal Errors

Tags: python, class, blackjack

I'm trying to create a blackjack game, and I'm learning dataclass decorator for cleaner code. I'm currently testing the classes, but I'm getting several errors. Here is the code:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field    
import random
from typing import List
import itertools

RANKS = '2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 J Q K A'.split()

SUITS = '♣ ♢ ♡ ♠'.split()


@dataclass
class Card:
"""Card Class for single card identification and for determining Ace value"""

    rank: str
    suit: str

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.rank} of {self.suit}"


@dataclass()    
class Player:
""" Player class for creating any # of players, give them a name/hand/bank """

    name: str
    values: int = 0
    # hand is a list of cards with an initial DEFAULT value of None
    hand: List[Card] = None
    # DEFAULT VALUES MUST BE STATED
    bank: int = 0

    def compute_card_value(self, card):
    # J, Q, K needs to be a rank of 10 check a specified list of all       
        possible card ranks
        if card in ["J", "Q", "K"]:
            value = 10
    # if value of hand is over 10 then value of ace = 1, else it will = 11
        elif card == "A":
            if self.values > 10:
                value = 1
            else:
                value = 11
        else:
        # numerical value for individual card which is passed as an argument/input
            value = int(card.rank)
        return value

    def add_card_to_hand(self, card):
        self.hand.append(card)
        self.values += self.compute_card_value(card)

    @dataclass()
    class Dealer(Player):
    
    """Dealer will need to be able to have their own hand, and display only the second card after initial deal"""
    
        def show_dealer_hand(self):
        return f"Dealer is showing {self.hand[0]}"


""" Using itertools to define a function to create a deck out of existing global variables RANKS & SUITS"""

def new_deck():    
    new_deck = [Card(r, s) for r, s in itertools.product(RANKS, SUITS)]
    return new_deck    


@dataclass()
class Deck:
    """Deck will create a deck with all normal deck ranks/suits in a list. Shuffle deck. Deal one card. Also return str """

    all_cards: List[Card] = field(default_factory=new_deck)

    def shuffle_deck(self):
        random.shuffle(self.all_cards)

    def deal_card(self):
        return self.all_cards.pop(0)

    def __repr__(self):
        str_cards = ", ".join([str(card) for card in self.all_cards])
        return str_cards

blkjck_deck = Deck()
blkjck_deck.shuffle_deck()

alex = Player("Alex", bank=200)

dealer = Dealer("Dealer")

list_of_players = []

for _ in range(2):
    new_card = blkjck_deck.deal_card()
    dealer.add_card_to_hand(new_card)

print(dealer.hand)
```

**### I tried dealing some cards to the dealer. I'm getting:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/abala/PycharmProjects/Milestone_2_Blackjack/main_2.py", line 94, in <module>
    dealer.add_card_to_hand(new_card)
  File "C:/Users/abala/PycharmProjects/Milestone_2_Blackjack/main_2.py", line 48, in add_card_to_hand
    self.hand.append(card)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

**If I change the hand (Player Class) into a basic list without None type, I start getting other errors when one or both cards are J, Q, K, or A:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/abala/PycharmProjects/Milestone_2_Blackjack/main_2.py", line 98, in <module>
    dealer.add_card_to_hand(new_card)
  File "C:/Users/abala/PycharmProjects/Milestone_2_Blackjack/main_2.py", line 53, in add_card_to_hand
    self.values += self.compute_card_value(card)
  File "C:/Users/abala/PycharmProjects/Milestone_2_Blackjack/main_2.py", line 48, in compute_card_value
    value = int(card.rank)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'A'
```

Please let me know what I'm not getting here.

Comment: `hand: List[Card] = None` initializes `self.hand` to `None`. You should initialize it to an empty list

Comment: I tried that and I started getting the second problem at the bottom of the original post.

Answer (score 2):

To fix the first error, you need to initialize `Player.hand` to an empty list, not `None`

```
    hand: List[Card] = []
```

To fix the second problem, your `if` statements should be checking `card.rank`, not `card`, to detect if it's a face card.

```
    def compute_card_value(self, card):
    # J, Q, K needs to be a rank of 10 check a specified list of all       
        possible card ranks
        if card.rank in ["J", "Q", "K"]:
            value = 10
    # if value of hand is over 10 then value of ace = 1, else it will = 11
        elif card.rank == "A":
            if self.values > 10:
                value = 1
            else:
                value = 11
        else:
        # numerical value for individual card which is passed as an argument/input
            value = int(card.rank)
        return value
```